# Why would one choose Firebase Cloud Messaging instead of an Intent Service?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating an android app which has a chat feature. I would like to create a notification if a new message arrives when the chat is not open. My messages are stored in a firebase database. I see two options for creating these notifications. One is to use the firebase function to trigger a firebase cloud message. The other is to use an Intent Service which runs an onChildAdded Event handler. The Intent Service seems much easier to me. Am I missing something? What would be a good reason to use Cloud Messaging over an Intent Service with the event handler running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried your Service will keep running all the time (and draining your battery), then that's a good reason to use the cloud function. Moreover, there are chances are that your service might get killed.

> Because only a few processes are generally
>   visible to the user, this means that the service should not be killed
>   except in low memory conditions. However, since the user is not
>   directly aware of a background service, in that state it is considered
>   a valid candidate to kill, and you should be prepared for this to
>   happen. In particular, long-running services will be increasingly
>   likely to kill and are guaranteed to be killed (and restarted if
>   appropriate) if they remain started long enough.

Finally, all the fuss you'd have to go through to deliver the results to an activity might be as painful as developing a cloud function.

In the company I work we decided to use the cloud function and it was pretty easy. We only needed to keep track of the FCM token of the devices and our function would monitor a certain node in our Real Time database. Every time somebody wrote there we'd get warned and would be able to act on it (grab the node, identify sender and receiver and with the saved FCM token send the notifications). We've used this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397) to achieve what we wanted. Some links on how to write the cloud function, [here](https://mobikul.com/sending-notification-firebase-cloud-functions/), [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) and a So question that I also used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440736/android-cloud-function-for-chat). The official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) too.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't show how to create notifications. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: About how to write the cloud functions? Sure, just added an edit :)

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks :)